# Add protocol-mapper to keycloak using kcadm.sh

Tags: keycloak

I have been trying to setup my full test system in keycloak using the kcadmin cli, but I have some problems creating protocol mappers:

*HTTP error - 400 Bad Request*

I have been trying to implement a request using:

http://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/3.3/rest-api/index.html
http://blog.keycloak.org/2017/01/administer-keycloak-server-from-shell.html

Am I missing something in the request:

```
/opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh create \
clients/7e8ef93b-0d0f-487d-84a5-5cfaee7ddf13/protocol-mappers/models \
-r $test_realm \
-s config.user.attribute=tenants \
-s config.claim.name=tenants \
-s config.jsonType.label=String \
-s config.id.token.claim=true \
-s config.access.token.claim=true \
-s config.userinfo.token.claim=true \
-s config.multivalued=true \
-s name=tenants \
-s protocolMapper=oidc-usermodel-attribute-mapper
```

This works:

```
/opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh create \
clients/7e8ef93b-0d0f-487d-84a5-5cfaee7ddf13/protocol-mappers/models \
-r $test_realm \
-s name=tenants1 \
-s protocol=openid-connect \
-s protocolMapper=oidc-usermodel-attribute-mapper
```

Comment: did you figure out how to set the config values?

Comment: i figured it out.  In windows, it's -s "config.\"access.token.claim\"=true"

Comment: I needed single quotes to make it work on windows inside a powershell script: -s 'config.\"access.token.claim\"=true'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the failing example the following value is missing:
`-s protocol=openid-connect`

Answer (score 8):

You need to specify nested config values like this in Linux:

```
-s 'config."id.token.claim"=true'
-s 'config."included.client.audience"=theclient'
```

Comment: but why ... just why :D
You saved hours of my life thx a loooot!!

Comment: How would you do this in Windows 10 or Win2k16 Server?

Comment: <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3

Answer (score 0):

After spending quite some time on how to run this in a PowerShell script on windows, this is what we came up with:

```
./kcadm.bat create clients/6fc086af-a474-4c5f-a1b0-edf806383f58/protocol-mappers/models -r realmName -s name="xxx" -s protocol="openid-connect" -s protocolMapper="oidc-usermodel-attribute-mapper" -s 'config.\"user.attribute\"=xxx'
```