# keycloak - Add protocol-mapper to keycloak using kcadm.sh

Tags: keycloak

I'm trying to add a hardcoded claim.  Following this post, I was able to create the claim partially.

How do I set:

```
config.jsonType.label=String
```

AND

`config.access.token.claim=true`

I was able to find the create the initial part of the hardcoded claim based on this post: [Add protocol-mapper to keycloak using kcadm.sh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47158634/add-protocol-mapper-to-keycloak-using-kcadm-sh#)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  `-s "config.\"access.token.claim\"=true"`

```
kcadm create clients/6842adac-982d-4b89-88b0-22b68a332807/protocol-mappers/models -r demorealm -s name=aud1 -s protocol=openid-connect -s protocolMapper=oidc-hardcoded-claim-mapper -s "config.\"access.token.claim\"=true"
```