# kcadm adding a new protocol-mapper

Tags: keycloak

I am trying to create a new oidc-usermodel-realm-mapper in my keycloak 
 3.4.3 instance however when i run this i get a

> HTTP error - 500 Internal   Server Error.

I know that kcadm is working as i can get clients and run other commands 
 such as create other mappers. Could there possibly be a bug in keycloak 
 for running this particular command?

```
/opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh create \
clients/428c2e48-77d0-43b7-aae4-0cc989ca4ee7/protocol-mappers/models \
-r demorealm \
-s protocol=openid-connect \
-s protocolMapper=oidc-usermodel-realm-mapper \
-s consentRequired=false \
-s config.claim.name=group_membership \
-s config.jsonType.label=String \
-s config.id.token.claim=true \
-s config.access.token.claim=true \
-s config.userinfo.token.claim=true \
-s config.multivalued=true \
-s name=Realm \
--server <url/auth> \
--user <user> \
--password <password>
```

the error in the server.log is;

> 2018-07-27 15:14:19,935 ERROR 
>       [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (default task-109) 
>       Uncaught server error:
>
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not
>       at [Source: io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl@55dee6f8; 
>       line: 1, column: 119] (through reference chain:
>
> org.keycloak.representations.idm.ProtocolMapperRepresentation["co
>          at
>
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:270)
>
> at
>
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportMappingException(DeserializationContext.java:1234)
>
> at
>
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1122)
>
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1075)
>
> at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:60)

Appreciate any assistance with this.

Answer (score 3):

Solution from [Add protocol-mapper to keycloak using kcadm.sh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47158634/add-protocol-mapper-to-keycloak-using-kcadm-sh)

You need to specify nested config values like this in Linux:

```
-s 'config."claim.name"=group_membership'
-s 'config."jsonType.label"=String'
```