# Getting "500 Internal Server Error" when trying to create oidc-full-name-mapper via kcadm.sh

Tags: keycloak

I am using Keycloak kcadm.sh tool to define a client. I am now trying to define protocol mappers similar to the ones that can be defined by the Keycloak's Web interface. The following command executes successfully:

./kcadm.sh create clients/myclientid/protocol-mappers/models -r myrealm -s name="full name" -s protocolMapper=oidc-full-name-mapper -s protocol=openid-connect

However when I examine the created full name mapper, I see that it's created with "Add to ID token" - OFF, and "Add to access token" - OFF. I want them to be ON. So, after deleting the created mapper I tried adding -s config.access.token.claim=true -s config.id.token.claim=true to the above command. So the command becomes:

./kcadm.sh create clients/myclientid/protocol-mappers/models -r myrealm -s name="full name" -s protocolMapper=oidc-full-name-mapper -s protocol=openid-connect -s config.access.token.claim=true -s config.id.token.claim=true

but this results in "HTTP error - 500 Internal Server Error"

I tried creating a mapper with the options turned off as before, then setting them on using the Web interface, then exporting the client and examine the result. The resulting json includes the following protocol mapper for my client:

```
"protocolMappers": [
    {
      "id": "...",
      "name": "full name",
      "protocol": "openid-connect",
      "protocolMapper": "oidc-full-name-mapper",
      "consentRequired": false,
      "config": {
        "id.token.claim": "true",
        "access.token.claim": "true"
      }
    }
  ],
```

so it seems that the path I gave was correct. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! On Linux, I had to use \" after the config. So the command became:
./kcadm.sh create clients/myclientid/protocol-mappers/models -r myrealm -s name="full name" -s protocolMapper=oidc-full-name-mapper -s protocol=openid-connect -s config.\"access.token.claim\"=true -s config.\"id.token.claim\"=true

JustinT's (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1717360/justint) comment to 
[Add protocol-mapper to keycloak using kcadm.sh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47158634/add-protocol-mapper-to-keycloak-using-kcadm-sh) gave me the direction.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the config values in Linux like this:

```
-s 'config."id.token.claim"=true'
-s 'config."access.token.claim"=true'
```