# Create protocol mapper in Keycloak using kcadm.sh

Tags: keycloak

From [Add protocol-mapper to keycloak using kcadm.sh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47158634/add-protocol-mapper-to-keycloak-using-kcadm-sh)

Has anyone figured this out yet? I tried it the way Oscar suggested and it still does not work.
The lines that are not commented work perfectly.

The lines that are commented do not work. I get an error that says "./clientmapper.sh: 59 (or whatever line number that I have uncommented): -s: not found"

```
    sudo docker exec $keycontainer /opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh create \
    clients/$cid/protocol-mappers/models \
    -r myrealm \
    -s name=roles \
    -s protocol=openid-connect \
    -s protocolMapper=oidc-usermodel-attribute-mapper
    #-s 'config."id.token.claim"=true' \
    #-s claim.name=roles \
    #-s jsonType.label=String \
    #-s multivalued=true \
    #-s userinfo.token.claim=true \
    #-s access.token.claim=true
```

Answer (score 4):

I made this work by formatting as Oscar suggested and using -i after the docker exec command.  It works perfectly now.

```
    sudo docker exec -i $keycontainer /opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh create \
    clients/$cid/protocol-mappers/models \
     -r testrealm \
     -s name=testmap \
     -s protocol=openid-connect \
     -s protocolMapper=oidc-usermodel-realm-role-mapper \
     -s 'config."id.token.claim"=true' \
     -s 'config."claim.name"=testmap' \
     -s 'config."jsonType.label"=String' \
     -s 'config."multivalued"=true' \
     -s 'config."userinfo.token.claim"=true' \
     -s 'config."access.token.claim"=true'
```