# Enable multiple audience in keycloak via kcadm

Tags: command-line, keycloak

I have microservice ecosystem and all users interacting with it need to authenticate to a keycloak installation and receive a jwt token.

All is fine, I enabled audience support using this snippet:

```
/opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh \
    create clients/d3170ee6-7778-413b-8f41-31479bdb2166/protocol-mappers/models -r your-realm \
    -s name=audience-mapping \
    -s protocol=openid-connect \
    -s protocolMapper=oidc-audience-mapper \
    -s config.\"included.client.audience\"="your-audience" \
    -s config.\"access.token.claim\"="true" \
    -s config.\"id.token.claim\"="false"
```

as described here: [Add protocol-mapper to keycloak using kcadm.sh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47158634/add-protocol-mapper-to-keycloak-using-kcadm-sh)

Which is fine, it works. My problem is, how do I enable multiple values for audience? I mean, I would like to allow the same user to use 2 different services with the same token - each of them should have a different audience.

And the token should look like:

```
{
  "aud": [
    "audience-1",
    "audience-2"
  ]
}
```

Where `audience-1` is the audience expected by the first service and `audience-2` is the one expected by the 2nd service.

Is it even possible to do that via command line?

Comment: did you solve this problem?

Comment: I think I just did. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have found the answer. Or at least it worked for me:

```
kcadm.sh create clients/CLIENT_ID/protocol-mappers/models -r REALM_NAME \
  -s name=audience-mapping \
  -s prodocol=openid-connect \
  -s protocolMapper=oidc-audience-mapper \
  -s config.\"included.client.audience\"="audience" \
  -s config.\"access.token.claim\"=\"true\" \
  -s config.\"id.token.claim\"=\"false\"
```

Comment: You mind showing how this differs from the initial code in your question? The only difference is "audience" vs "your-audience" How did this resolve your issue?

Comment: It's been a while, but I think that's was the "fix". The word "audience" in the sense that it needed to add the claim there.