# Where are all of the Keycloak Protocol Mapper Config Options documented?

Tags: java, keycloak, keycloak-services

I'm using Keycloak's Java `keycloak-admin-client` and I'm wanting to set up some protocol mappers for my realm's client.

The Java API exposes this class to create a protocol mapper and then the following method to set the config options:

```java
    ProtocolMapperRepresentation protocolMapperRep = new ProtocolMapperRepresentation();
    protocolMapperRep.setConfig(Map.of("some.mapper.config.option", "mapper-value"));
```

I've looked at the javadoc documentation and it's, well, completely useless unfortunately. :( I have not looked at the rest-api documentation, but I just looked at it and it doesn't do anything to enumerate the config options for the protocol mapper representation: https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/12.0/rest-api/index.html#_protocolmapperrepresentation

I saw a few options from another StackOverflow question here: [Add protocol-mapper to keycloak using kcadm.sh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47158634/add-protocol-mapper-to-keycloak-using-kcadm-sh)

However, there *has* to be a better place where these are documented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically, what you can do is to first look at [Rest API Documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/21.0.1/rest-api/index.html#_protocol_mappers_resource) and the [Keycloak API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/21.0.1/javadocs/org/keycloak/representations/idm/ProtocolMapperRepresentation.html).

Alternatively, and this *almost* always work, you just create the protocol Mapper using the Keycloak Admin API, for instance:

[image]

Then before clicking `Save`, open your browser developer network console and look at the network requests. Then click `save`:

You will have two post request, one for the token, another for the creation of the mapper:

[image]

Look at the request payload, you will see something as:

```json
{
  "protocol": "openid-connect",
  "config": {
    "multivalued": "true",
    "id.token.claim": "true",
    "access.token.claim": "true",
    "userinfo.token.claim": "true",
    "claim.name": "asdas"
  },
  "name": "asdas",
  "protocolMapper": "oidc-usermodel-realm-role-mapper"
}
```

Now you can infer the options from there. Not ideal I know.

Answer (score 2):

The list for Keycloak 15 is the following (missing only the Pairwise Subject Identifier):

- oidc-usersessionmodel-note-mapper
- oidc-group-membership-mapper
- oidc-usermodel-attribute-mapper
- oidc-usermodel-realm-role-mapper
- oidc-audience-mapper
- oidc-usermodel-property-mapper
- oidc-hardcoded-claim-mapper
- oidc-hardcoded-role-mapper
- oidc-allowed-origins-mapper
- oidc-audience-resolve-mapper
- oidc-claims-param-token-mapper
- oidc-usermodel-client-role-mapper
- oidc-full-name-mapper
- oidc-address-mapper
- oidc-role-name-mapper

Comment: hey jeremie, source?

Answer (score 1):

I found myself here as I was looking for documentation about the different Keycloak protocol mapper types, and for anyone else who is doing the same, I can confirm that it's difficult.

The [protocol mappers section](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_protocol-mappers) in the Keycloak Server Admin guide is pretty clear that it is not going to walk users through all of the details. See the excerpt below (emphasis mine).

> Protocol mappers map items (such as an email address, for example) to
> a specific claim in the identity and access token. **The function of a
> mapper should be self-explanatory from its name.** You add
> pre-configured mappers by clicking Add Builtin.
>
> Each mapper has a set of common settings. Additional settings are
> available, depending on the mapper type. Click Edit next to a mapper
> to access the configuration screen to adjust these settings.

[This](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/20.0.1/javadocs/org/keycloak/protocol/oidc/mappers/package-summary.html) is the closest thing I've found to documentation of the different protocol mapper types.

I like @dreamcrash's approach to the problem.